# curl_close() not writing CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR session file from PHP 8 onwards

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

For those that are encountering a *session file* bug, where `cURL` **does not write anything** inside `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` (although the file exists and is writable), with this setup:

1. **PHP 8.0 onwards**
2. *stateful* request being made with **PHP cURL**
3. `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and/or `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` set to a *readable/writable* location
4. using `curl_close()` to close the handle

### TL;DR;

**Don't rely on curl_close()**. Use `unset($curlHandle)` or `$curlHandle = null` after you're done with the cURL request.

Credits: [@volkerschulz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22629028/volkerschulz)

### Why this happens

The problem is related to this: [PHP's curl_close() documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-close.php)

As stated on the documentation of `curl_close()`, *This function has no effect. Prior to PHP 8.0.0, this function was used to close the resource.*

Misleadingly, [CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), states that `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` should be filled with *The name of a file to save all internal cookies to **when the handle is closed, e.g. after a call to curl_close**.*

### Cross-compatibility between PHP 5.6, 7.x and 8.x

In order to patch code that must be guaranteed to work on multiple PHP versions, just follow this pattern:

```php
$ch = curl_init($url);
...
...
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
// always unset curl handle after having closed it.
unset($ch);
```

#### Reproducible example

This is a sample code to reproduce the problem.

Use it like this:

1. **with patch** : `/usr/bin/php8.x test.php --with-patch`
2. **without the patch** : `/usr/bin/php8.x test.php`

```php
<?php

// exit if not called from CLI
if (php_sapi_name() !== 'cli') {
    die('This script can only be called from CLI');
}

// exit if the major version of PHP is not 8 or greater
if (substr(phpversion(), 0, 1) < 8) {
    die('This script requires PHP 8 or greater');
}

// exit if we don't have cURL support
if (! function_exists('curl_init')) {
    die('This script requires cURL support');
}

// get the command line option "--with-patch" (if any)
$withPatch = in_array('--with-patch', $argv);
$withPatchClaim = $withPatch ? 'with the unset($ch) patch' : 'without the unset($ch) patch';

// get the major+minor version of PHP
$phpVersion = substr(phpversion(), 0, 3);

// get the version of the cUrl module (if available)
$curlVersion = curl_version()['version'];

echo "Testing with PHP {$phpVersion}, cURL {$curlVersion}. Running {$withPatchClaim}\n";

// define our base path
$basepath = dirname(__FILE__);

// setup a randomic session file for cURL in the current directory, for debugging purposes
$rand = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$sessionFile = "{$basepath}/{$rand}.txt";
file_put_contents($sessionFile, '');

// init a curl request to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/320782/any-benefit-in-replacing-a-varchar-for-an-index-in-the-main-table
// this url is intended to save cookies in the session file
$url = 'https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/320782/any-benefit-in-replacing-a-varchar-for-an-index-in-the-main-table';
$ch = curl_init($url);
if (! $ch) {
    die('Could not initialize a cURL session');
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding: utf-8',
    'Accept-Charset: utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
    'Cache-Control: no-cache',
    'Connection: Keep-Alive',
    'Referer: https://www.google.com/',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/118.0',
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// see https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COOKIELIST.html
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIELIST, 'FLUSH');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $sessionFile);
// this would not work even with CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE pointing to the same file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

// execute the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
$effectiveUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
$httpStatusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$primaryIp = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_PRIMARY_IP);
// as of PHP 8 onwards, the curl_close() call has no effect: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-close.php
curl_close($ch);

// if we've called this script with "--with-patch", apply the @volkerschulz patch https://stackoverflow.com/a/77261355/1916292
if ($withPatch) {
    unset($ch);
    // the garbage collection is not needed.
    // it is intentionally left here to let the reader understand that the issue is related to destroying the $ch variable
    gc_collect_cycles();
}

// make the response a one-liner
$response = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', str_replace([chr(13).chr(10), chr(10), chr(9)], ' ', $response));

// print the response (cap to a max of 128 chars)
echo "GET {$effectiveUrl} ({$httpStatusCode})\n";
echo "Primary IP: {$primaryIp}\n";
echo "Error: {$error}\n";
echo 'Response: '.substr($response, 0, 128)." ...\n";

// debug the contents of the session file
echo str_repeat('-', 80)."\n";
echo "Session file: {$sessionFile}\n";

// show the difference from $withPatch and without it
if (! $withPatch) {
    echo "Session file contents without the unset(\$ch) patch (BUGGED):\n";
    echo 'Session Filesize: '.filesize($sessionFile)."\n";
    echo file_get_contents($sessionFile)."\n";
} else {
    echo "Session file contents WITH the unset(\$ch) patch (WORKING):\n";
    echo 'Session Filesize: '.filesize($sessionFile)."\n";
    echo file_get_contents($sessionFile)."\n";
}
```

Script output **with patch enabled**:

```
maurizio:~/test (master ?) $ php8.2 test.php
Testing with PHP 8.2, cURL 7.81.0. Running without the unset($ch) patch
GET https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/320782/any-benefit-in-replacing-a-varchar-for-an-index-in-the-main-table (200)
Primary IP: 104.18.10.86
Error:
Response: HTTP/2 200 date .... (OMISSIS)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
Session file: /home/maurizio/test/100881e90c76fd3a63ee2e6b3b710fea.txt
Session file contents without the unset($ch) patch (BUGGED):
Session Filesize: 0
```

Script output **with patch enabled**:

```
maurizio:~/test (master ?) $ php8.2 test.php --with-patch
Testing with PHP 8.2, cURL 7.81.0. Running with the unset($ch) patch
GET https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/320782/any-benefit-in-replacing-a-varchar-for-an-index-in-the-main-table (200)
Primary IP: 104.18.10.86
Error:
Response: HTTP/2 200 date .... (OMISSIS)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Session file: /home/maurizio/test/aa1524b52055bad838f18fae44e83b22.txt
Session file contents WITH the unset($ch) patch (WORKING):
Session Filesize: 431
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# https://curl.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

#HttpOnly_.stackexchange.com    TRUE    /       TRUE    1696928967      __cf_bm OMISSIS
#HttpOnly_.stackexchange.com    TRUE    /       TRUE    1728549567      prov    OMISSIS
```

Comment: I just reproduced this in PHP 8.2.7.

Comment: On my Mac I have PHP 7.4 cURL 8.2.1. But on my Linux server I have PHP 8.2.7 cURL 7.88.1.

Comment: My guess is it's using buffered output to the file, and it's not flushing the buffer. It gets flushed automatically when the script ends.

Comment: @Barmar I've just added the "Edit 1" on the question, following your suggestion. The problem still persists - and sincerely don't know how it may be possible.

Comment: The shutdown function may be running before the file is flushed.

Comment: Running Testing with PHP 8.1, cURL 7.88.1, although it says Session Filesize: 0 - the file actually contains 6 lines after the script has finished.

Comment: One thing which can point to some difference in versions is from the manual for [curl_close](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-close.php) - This function has no effect. Prior to PHP 8.0.0, this function was used to close the resource.

Comment: Excellent bugreport, I would say. Please file that on bugs.php.net! Question though, there are quite a few calls that didn't get their returnvalue checked for errors, does any of them fail in one or the other case?

Comment: Have you tried `unset($ch);` to see if it triggers the old `curl_close()` behaviour?

Comment: @user1191247 : unset does the trick on my puter (mac ventura, php8.2.9, curl 8.2.1).  Curl works, the file is created and has the appropriate content.  Just unseting $ch made `filesize` and `file_get_content` happy again.  Seems like a bug.

Comment: Here's a related [bug report](https://github.com/php/doc-en/issues/2239) on github.

Comment: `$ch = null;` right after `curl_close($ch);` works as well.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your contributions. The issue is solved. I'll update my answer, giving correct instructions and a meaningful title.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question

Comment: @PeeHaa if you only had a quick view to /77260319/revisions, you'll have noticed that it originally *indeed was* a question. Then, after the community contributions, I've modified the scope of the question to be of help to PHP people arriving there with the same obscure problem. IMHO, there are a ton of "no-question" questions, where the original answer has been repurposed to be of great help, instead having to dig into answers and comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of PHP 8.0.0 `curl_init()` no longer returns a *resource* but rather an *object* of type *CurlHandle*. This object will not get destroyed automatically before the garbage collector jumps into action after the PHP script exits.

The documentation for *CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR* states:

> The name of a file to save all internal cookies to when the handle is closed, e.g. after a call to curl_close.

The last part is misleading, of course, because as of PHP 8.0.0 `curl_close()` has no effect anymore, according to its documentation.

If you want to force close the handle (i.e. destroy the object) you need to either

```
unset($ch);
```

or put

```
$ch = null;
```

Comment: thank you for your contribution. The documentation of CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR is indeed misleading, and one can easily relate the problem to something else, instead of understanding the curl_close() difference from PHP 8.0 onwards. I'll update my answer, giving correct instructions and a meaningful title.

Comment: One could argue that the mentioning of `curl_close` is only an 'example given' and still applies to older PHP versions, but I agree 100% that there should be clarification inside the docs.