# Cannot delete cURL Cookie File since upgrade to PHP 8.2

Tags: php, curl

The following script (stripped down for clarity and simplicity) has run fine for years, but since upgrading from php 5 to 8, the cookie file created is no longer deleted by the unlink command, despite it reporting success, leading to a build-up of these cookie files.

If I take out the CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR line, then the file is deleted just fine.

```
<?php
    $my_cookie=tempnam("./","XX");
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $my_cookie);
    curl_close($ch);    
    
    if (unlink($my_cookie)) {    
        echo "success - $my_cookie unlinked<BR>";
    } else {
        echo "fail";    
    }
?>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curl_close($ch);` does nothing in PHP >= 8.0.0, so the cookie file doesn't actually exist (yet) when you're trying to delete it.

Replace `curl_close($ch);` with `unset($ch);`. This will write the cookie file.

[See documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-close.php) of `curl_close`:

> **Note:**
> This function has no effect. Prior to PHP 8.0.0, this function was used to close the resource.

Comment: Thanks this seems to have worked, thank you!  
I don't fully understand what was going wrong though... when was the cookie file being written, if it wasn't before I tried to delete it?

Comment: @A1Dan The cookie file gets written when the resource / handle is closed / disposed. Before PHP 8 that happened with `curl_close`. Since with PHP 8 `curl_close` does nothing, the cookie file won't get written before the script exits (and the handle is garbage collected). By using `unset` you dispose the handle explicitly. - If the answer has helped, please accept (and upvote of you can).

Comment: duplicate answer ?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77261355/915467 .  I dont get the dogma that leads to the referenced question to be closed as a 'not a programming question'   .02

Comment: Still going over my head... was the cookie file only being written after the attempted unlink, when the script exits then?  Why does it get written at that point?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Good question **why** that is. It probably wasn't the smartest decision by the PHP guys to simply make `curl_close` a `noop`. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Try using an absolute path: curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($my_cookie) );

Comment: No improvement I'm afraid!